# Proving a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is limited. Where do I begin?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $F(\lambda x, \lambda y) = F(x, y)$ for all $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$ and $\lambda \neq 0$. Prove that $F$ is limited.

I'm lost on where to start this. Would be very grateful to anyone who could help me.

Comment: Do you know that a continuous function on a compact set is bounded/limited? Can you use this fact along with the relation given to you?

Comment: I do. But I'm having trouble relating that to what I'm being asked to prove.

Comment: Here's one approach: prove that in a compact region $K$ around the origin (e.g. the closed unit disc), $f$ is bounded (because $f$ is continuous). Then show that you can shrink any other vector so that it fits within $K$. And the value of $f$ on the shrunk vector is related to the value of $f$ on the original vector...

Comment: The fact that I can shrink any other vector so that it fits within K comes directly from $F(λx, λy) = F(x, y)$, right?

Comment: Yes! If $K$ is the closed unit disc, then you can put $\lambda$ equal to the reciprocal of the length of that vector. That'll shrink the vector to make it a unit vector. You can even make the vector shorter than that if you pick $\lambda$ to be smaller than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact $F$ must be constant. Proof: For any $p$ on the unit circle, define $R_p$ to be the ray $\{rp: r>0 \}.$ From the hypothesis, $F$ is constant on $R_p.$ By  continuity, this constant value must be $F(0,0).$ Since $p$ was an aribtrary point on the unit circle, we see $F=F(0,0)$ on every $R_p.$ Hence $F\equiv F(0,0)$ on $\mathbb R^2.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ be the closed unit ball around the origin in $ \mathbb{R}^2$. Because $K$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, $f$ is bounded on the compact set $K$ — this means that its value is always between some limits $a$ and $b$.

Now if $x$ is any other point in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we will show that $a\leq f(x) \leq b$ which will prove that $f$ is bounded everywhere.

We can shrink $x$ so that it's in the closed unit ball $K$: we know that, for example, $x^\prime \equiv x/4||x||$ is in $K$. Hence $a \leq f(x^\prime) \leq b$. But we also know that $f(x) = f(x^\prime)$ by the defining property of $f$. Hence $a \leq f(x) \leq b$.

Comment: You mention "... if x is any other point in $R^2$..." and then "... we can shrink x...". How do you shrink a point? I'm having trouble understanding your reply. Thanks!

Comment: I think that F being limited follows directy from the fact that F(x, y) is a continuous function on a compact set, so it's image must also be compact, but I'm not sure that's right.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Sorry for the confusion. Here when I say "shrink", I mean "find a scalar multiple of $x$ which is shorter in length". In particular, we can find a multiple of $x$ which lies within the closed unit disk $K$.

Comment: The domain of $F$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, which isn't compact --- so we don't know automatically that $F$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^2$. But because of the theorem you propose, we do know that $F$ is bounded on $K$, the closed unit disk.  From there, $F$ has the property that $F(x) = F(\alpha x)$, so we can extended the boundedness to any multiple of a point in $K$ --- which is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.